# turkish language issues in my web page MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i developed web page have a Turkish language but i have some issues when render in browser,
note: i make this localization in XML File [image]

Comment: Did you set `encoding` for your XML file?

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you for your question , yes i encoded it

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your layuot view head section:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8; Cache-Control: no-cache" />
    <!- other markup --> 
</head>
```

Comment: @Osamakhodrog post your action and view code related to problem, it should help a bit.